# Jsoup on Android - OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

If I try to parse some html document, it is cause this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.Object.internalClone(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.clone(Object.java:82)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:172)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:224)
at org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser.emit(Tokeniser.java:76)
at org.jsoup.parser.TokeniserState$1.read(TokeniserState.java:26)
at org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser.read(Tokeniser.java:42)
at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.runParser(TreeBuilder.java:101)
at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:53)
at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:24)
at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:31)
at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:81)
at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.load(DataUtil.java:37)
at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:89)
```

But if I try to parse earlier version of this document, that size is more, this error don't appear.

Comment: How does your parsing code look?

Comment: Ive gottent this error before. If i see how you parse the information i may be able to decipher why you are getting the error.

Comment: This error arrear in method Jsoup.parse(). I am parsing html file from SD card.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know what you are using to connect to the document because i cant see your code, but this is how is usually do it

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

url can be the path to your HTML document.

Comment: I parse document from file, don't from URL:
File input = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(),"index.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");